# Python can't compile lanms on windows -EAST

Tags: python, opencv, ocr

i get the text in the picture into a rectangle. For this, i am using EAST: An Efficient and Accurate Scene Text Detector 
my using below example
https://github.com/kurapan/EAST

I runing this below code

```py
import subprocess
import os
import numpy as np

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))

if subprocess.call(['make', '-C', BASE_DIR]) != 0:  # return value
    raise RuntimeError('Cannot compile lanms: {}'.format(BASE_DIR))


def merge_quadrangle_n9(polys, thres=0.3, precision=10000):
    from .adaptor import merge_quadrangle_n9 as nms_impl
    if len(polys) == 0:
        return np.array([], dtype='float32')
    p = polys.copy()
    p[:,:8] *= precision
    ret = np.array(nms_impl(p, thres), dtype='float32')
    ret[:,:8] /= precision
    return ret
```

But, i got this error

```py
Using TensorFlow backend.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\LENOVA\Desktop\east\EAST-master\eval.py", line 11, in <module>
    from lanms import *
  File "C:\Users\LENOVA\Desktop\east\EAST-master\lanms\__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    if subprocess.call(['make', '-C', BASE_DIR]) != 0:  # return value
  File "C:\Users\LENOVA\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\subprocess.py", line 267, in call
    with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as p:
  File "C:\Users\LENOVA\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\subprocess.py", line 707, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "C:\Users\LENOVA\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\subprocess.py", line 990, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

Comment: See [How to compile lanms on Windows](https://github.com/argman/EAST/issues/120) as pointed out at the bottom of [README](https://github.com/argman/EAST).

Answer (score 1):

I have tried commenting below two lines in `lanms/__init__.py`:

```py
if subprocess.call(['make', '-C', BASE_DIR]) != 0:  # return value
    raise RuntimeError('Cannot compile lanms: {}'.format(BASE_DIR))
```

It is working for me. for the above mentioned error.